# Magento2 - How to export order grid data programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, export

I want to export my order grid's data programmatically. I am calling the `execute` method of `/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToCsv.php` by passing necessary parameters, like `filters`, `namespace`, etc. But it is giving me error as below:

> "DOMDocument should be created".

This is because it is trying to get the UIComponent based on the namespace that I pass i.e. `sales.order.grid` when generating the CSVFile and it's getting null in UIComponent. Should I create a mock of the UIComponent, if yes, then how can I do it and/or is there any other way ?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
//***************variables in construct start***************
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv $converter,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\FileCollector\AggregatedFileCollector $fileCollector,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger $domMerger,
    \Magento\Framework\Component\DirSearch $dirSearch,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem

    $this->context       = $context;
    $this->converter     = $converter;
    $this->fileFactory   = $fileFactory;
    $this->fileCollector = $fileCollector;
    $this->domMerger     = $domMerger;
    $this->dirSearch     = $dirSearch;
    $this->filesystem    = $filesystem;
    $this->request       = $request;
//***************variables in construct end***************

//*************main method code starts here***************
$filters  = [
'created_at' => ['from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate],
'placeholder'=> true
];

$this->request->setParam('filters',$filters)
->setParam('namespace','sales_order_grid')
->setParam('search','')
->setParam('selected','false');

$obj = new \Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToCsv(
    $this->context,
    $this->converter,
    $this->fileFactory
);
$fileReader  = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
$fileContent = $fileReader->readFile('vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml');
$this->domMerger->merge($fileContent);
//$domDocument = $this->domMerger->createDomDocument($fileContent);
//$this->domMerger->setDom($domDocument);
$obj->execute();

//main method code ends here
```

Comment: Hi Reena, I also want to implement the order export through cron. If you have anything to share here, please do.

Comment: @RishabhRkRai I investigated it a long ago but i remember it was not possible using the existing GridToCsv controller, and I had to generate the CSV file programmatically.

Comment: can you please share some overview on this?